# What format to use for playing video from Internet on Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-encoding, android-videoview

I'm trying to load a video into a `VideoView` and `MediaController` with the following code:

```
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
          
mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(video);
mediaController.setAnchorView(footer);
video.setMediaController(mediaController);
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

If I use a .3gp file (such as [this](http://rtsp://v6.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnF4qJzpSt4nhMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYMDFmvL1wMysTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp)) it plays. But my MP4 file won't play just bringing up a dialog box saying:

> Sorry, this can't play this video

I accept the video may not be in the correct formats for such a purpose as I didn't make it a colleague did. What format should the videos be in?

I use Handbrake usually and am running Ubuntu.

Format Currently:

> **Video:**
>
> Dimensions: 1024 x 624
>
> CODEC: H.264 /AVC
>
> Framerate: 30 frames per second
>
> bitrate: 1307kbps
>
> **Audio:**
>
> CODEC: MPEG-4 AAC audio
>
> Channels: Stereo
>
> Sample rate: 44100 Hz
>
> Bitrate: 63kbps

Here are some errors from LogCat when playing it as a resource:

```
12-20 10:54:26.120: I/MediaPlayer(27966): uri is:android.resource://com.android.player/2130968576
12-20 10:54:26.120: I/MediaPlayer(27966): path is null
12-20 10:54:26.160: E/MediaPlayer(27966): Unable to to create media player
12-20 10:54:26.160: D/MediaPlayer(27966): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
12-20 10:54:26.160: I/MediaPlayer(27966): prepareAsync called in state 4
12-20 10:54:26.160: E/MediaPlayer(27966): error (1, -2147483648)
12-20 10:54:26.210: E/MediaPlayer(27966): Error (1,-2147483648)
12-20 10:54:26.210: D/VideoView(27966): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (16GB) running Honeycomb 3.1 - I understand it won't work in emulator.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the media format, AFAICS, but video streaming on Android is unspeakably broken and random. As a test, try copying your .mp4 clip to the sdcard and loading it from there.

Comment: As you mentioned media format, is supported by android, And also Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 supports .mp4 format.. So try to play other .mp4 video from sdcard on your galaxy tab..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had one of those light-bulb moments and discovered that the video was hosted on Amazon S3. Uploaded it to our IIS Web Server and it plays!